# One dropdown overwriting another's value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I'm making a page with javascript react and formik and I have two dropdowns in one form, I got them to work but now that I'm using both of them, when I choose a value with one the other's value resets. Don't know how to word this better so I'll add a gif of what happens:

[image: Dropdown overwriting example]

These are my drop down menus (both identical just taking values from a different object).

```
                  <Field
                    as="select"
                    className="custom-select d-block w-100"
                    name="fk_room"
                    required
                  >
                    <option></option>
                    {this.state.doctors.map((doctors) => (
                      <option value={doctors.surname} selected>
                        {" "}
                        {doctors.surname}
                      </option>
                    ))}
                  </Field>
```

I have a sneaking suspicion it's likely to do with me setting the state twice

```
  componentDidMount() {
    userService.getAllRooms().then((result) => {
      this.setState({
        rooms: result.map(({ name }) => name),
      });
    });
    userService.getAllEmployees().then((result) => {
        this.setState({
          doctors: result.map(o => ({name: o.name, surname: o.surname, specialization: o.specialization})),
        });
      });
  }
```

even though with console.log it looks like I get the values correctly, I assume something funky is going on since every dropdown click calls the componentDidMount again (I think).
Has anyone dealt with a similar issue? Does it have to do with me setting the state twice or I need to somehow save the value from the dropdowns? (It worked fine with just 1 dropdown menu where I called the state once).
Sorry if this is complete novice territory I am very inexperienced in javascript and react.
P.S. the dropdowns are completely independent, all the guides I found online were about dependent dropdown menus but this is not the final result I want, they both should never change from the initial call to fill the objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
 componentDidMount() {
    userService.getAllRooms().then((result) => {
      this.setState((state)=>({
        ...state,
        rooms: result.map(({ name }) => name),
      }));
    });
    userService.getAllEmployees().then((result) => {
        this.setState((state)=>({
           ...state,
          doctors: result.map(o => ({name: o.name, surname: o.surname, specialization: o.specialization})),
        });
      }));
  }
```